# Descriptor pool index 0 is out of range for the provided pools of size 0

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to run a simple BigQuery SELECT using the new Partition Logic. Running into the error.

While this is supported:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t._PARTITIONTIME, DAY)) AS time
FROM 
 `some_table` AS t
 WHERE
    (DATE(PARTITIONTIME) = DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP('2016-10-01 00:00:00'), DAY)))
```

The following is not supported:

```
 SELECT 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t._PARTITIONTIME, DAY)) AS time
 FROM 
  `some_table` AS t
 WHERE
  (DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t._PARTITIONTIME, DAY)) = DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP('2016-10-01 00:00:00'), DAY)))
```

Note how I just took TIMESTAMP_TRUNC from the SELECT Clause and put it into the WHERE. Not saying that this is a good practice - applying functions to the left side in the where clause is not efficient, but need to support this use case due to how Looker BI works (that we use on top of BigQuery).

Comment: can you clarify  - what is the question? if you are saying something is forced by Looker BI - what is this exactly?

Comment: Based on the question title, it sounds like you found a bug. Do you have a job ID for the failed query? That would help a BigQuery engineer look into it more and possibly provide a workaround.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant this ended up being a Looker bug. Happily resolved now.

Comment: nice - thank you for update!